# Can I get all the remainders?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If k and n are relative primes, do I get all the remainders (0, ..., n-1) from these numbers (mod n): 0, k, 2k, 3k, ..., (n-1)*k?
If so, what theorem is about this topic?
Also, what if they are not relative primes?

Comment: Yes, you get all. Look at this site for a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you get all the remainders.

How can you prove it?

> **Hint:** Show that all of those terms are distinct $\pmod{n}?

---

It's more of a "established fact" pretty early on, rather than a "theorem".

---

What do you think? What have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you do.  They do not have to be prime, they have to be relatively prime, which means having a $\gcd$ of $1$.  For example, $4$ and $9$ work just fine as $0, 9, 18, 27$ have distinct remainders $\bmod 4$.  The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) is what you are looking for.